# Flutter Gesture detector

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

How can I implement onHorizantalDragStart gesture detector given below in the picture and show these two buttons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkE7k.png)

Comment: Try this [Flutter slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) class which comes prebuilt in flutter with this you can create similar action.
[flutter_slidable](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable) is a pub package for the same feature

Edit: I just found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651974/swipe-list-item-for-more-options-flutter) which has more in-depth answers.

Comment: do upvote and accept if it helped. :xD